# How to round numbers?

Tags: php, calculation

7000 / 253000 = 0.027667984189723

```
$number1 = "7000";
$number2 = "253000";
$total = $number1 / $number2;
// return 0.027667984189723
```

This result how to round 2766 ?

Comment: how can you consider "2766" the rounded "0.027667984189723" thats not how maths works

Comment: please tell us what you have **tried** so far to [round](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) your number?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    echo round($total,5);
```

Answer (score 0):

$number1 / $number2 * 10000 % 1

Comment: While this may help OP, it's better to add more details, examples, etc.  Please [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you came up with 2766 as a result of your decimal. But I'm up for that challenge. Firstly, to get the correct decimal placing do:

```php
<?php echo round($total, 5); ?>
```

However, if you're like me, I'm going to figure out that challenge and have some fun with it:

```php
$num1 = round($total, 5); 
$num2 = strval($num1); 
$num3 = str_split($num2); 

$arr1 = array();
foreach ($num3 as $num) {
    if(is_string($num)) { 
        array_push($arr1, $num);
    }
}

$arr2 = array_slice($arr1, 3);

foreach($arr2 as $out) { 
    echo $out;
}
```

The expected output is 2767, since I did it with the correct round function.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it works for you i tried with different values its working good when value start with `0.`

```
$after_point = ltrim($total,"0.");  //27667984189723
echo  substr($v,0,4);               //2766
```

if you give `52.548457` then it return `52.5`

You must chack that number start with `0.`